# Module doesn't apperar in employee permissions in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I have developed a module for Prestashop , this is information in `__construct()` method :

```
$this->name = 'moduleName';
$this->tab = 'others';
$this->version = '1.0.0';
$this->author = 'programmer name';
$this->bootstrap = true;

parent::__construct();

$this->displayName = $this->l('name');
$this->description = $this->l('description);
```

but when I go to set permission for employee I can't find this module .

**Modules list**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this

```
$helper->allow_employee_form_lang = Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG', 0);
```

to the renderForm method where you helper is defined.